zxing does not recognize qrcodes from dymo printer
I try to read QRCode stickers from scanned documents via zxing lib for java. Unfortunately the code is working, but the qrcodes coming from my Dymo Printer are not recognized at all. Here is the code I am testing the qrcodes with:
Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<BarcodeFormat> possibleFormats = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
    possibleFormats.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    
    hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.FALSE);
    hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, possibleFormats);
    hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
    File f = new File("/tmp/qrcode/the-qrcode-generator.com⁄.png");
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    try {
        bi = ImageIO.read(f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.logExceptionSysOutEncapsulated(e, KickStarter.class);
    }
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(
            (Binarizer)new HybridBinarizer(
                    (LuminanceSource)new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
                            bi)));
        MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        try {
            Result resulta = reader.decode(binaryBitmap, hintMap);
            Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated(resulta.getText(), KickStarter.class);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            Logger.logExceptionSysOutEncapsulated(e, KickStarter.class);
        }

I know the Code is working, because if I try with a generated qrCode image from https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/ it works just fine. But the generated Codes from the Dymo Connect Software are not recognized whatsoever. So this works:

whereas this one is not working:

Can anyone familiar with the QRCode Standards see the problem here?

Have you tried downsizing the working QR code (to see if the size is an issue) and embedding it in a similar background?

Since you are converting the image to a binary image (with HybridBinarizer) the background may really be an issue.

No, not yet. I'll try that and post the results here. But I don't think the 'embedding' is the issue, as the qrcode is not working as a standalone image with no disturbing elements.

What I am especially interested in, is the difference in the images above. Both of them should encode "85000" but are completely different. Maybe I have the wrong configuration for my Dymo printer. Does anyone recognize the differences between the two QRCodes from above?

Both images contain the string "85000" and can be read by zbarimg on Linux.

Using Python tool "qrcode", the first image is produced with qr --error-correction=L 85000 and the second with qr --error-correction=M 85000. So the difference between the two images is the amount of error correction applied.

thank you for this hint. I feel like my solution is in a proper Dymoprinter config. Maybe zxing  can not handle this specific error-correction bit count, so I just need to get a "proper" format out of my printer...

I've made some tests and learned about QR Codes in general, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem. I've packed all the information in an answer down below ;)

I got it working. I don't know why, but the used hint map was no good. Apparently if I pass an empty Map, the QRCode is recognized and everything is fine. As soon as I use any Parameter in the Map, the NotFoundException is coming to haunt me. So my solution: empty HintMap!

So I spent yesterday night learning about QR Codes. I think I can read a QR Code "by hand" now, if I'd understand the Reel Solomon Codes ...
Nonetheless all my new knowledge does no thelp me. I've made a test program that generates QR Codes with ZXing and reads them after creating them:
    package com.ffleuchten.zxingtest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.ffleuchten.logger.Logger;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.Binarizer;
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.ErrorCorrectionLevel;

public class ZXingTest {

    public void run() {
        String qrCodeText = "zxing test";
        BufferedImage image = null;
        
        
        //generate QRCODE with error correction level l
        try {
            image = createQRImage(qrCodeText,0);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            Logger.logExceptionSysOutEncapsulated(e, getClass());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.logExceptionSysOutEncapsulated(e, getClass());
        }
        Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("QR Code(L) generated!", getClass());
        //read QRCODE with error correction level l
        
        String result = readQRImage(image);
        Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("QR Code read! Result is: " + result, getClass());
        
        
        //generate QRCODE with error correction level m
        try {
            image = createQRImage(qrCodeText,1);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            Logger.logExceptionSysOutEncapsulated(e, getClass());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.logExceptionSysOutEncapsulated(e, getClass());
        }
        Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("QR Code(M) generated!", getClass());
        //read QRCODE with error correction level m
        
        result = readQRImage(image);
        Logger.logInfoSysOutEncapsulated("QR Code read! Result is: " + result, getClass());
    }

    private static BufferedImage createQRImage(String qrCodeText, int errorCorrectionLevel)
            throws WriterException, IOException {
        Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<>();
        switch(errorCorrectionLevel) {
            case 0:
            hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
            break;
            case 1:
                hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
                break;
        }
        QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix byteMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(qrCodeText, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, Constants.DEFAULT_SIZE, Constants.DEFAULT_SIZE, hintMap);
        int matrixWidth = byteMatrix.getWidth();
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(matrixWidth, matrixWidth, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        image.createGraphics();

        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, matrixWidth, matrixWidth);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for (int i = 0; i < matrixWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixWidth; j++) {
                if (byteMatrix.get(i, j)) {
                    graphics.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return image;
        
    }
    private static String readQRImage(BufferedImage image) {
        Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<BarcodeFormat> possibleFormats = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
        possibleFormats.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
        
        hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.FALSE);
        hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, possibleFormats);
        
            BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(
                    (Binarizer)new HybridBinarizer(
                            (LuminanceSource)new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
                                    image)));
                Result result = null;
            try {
                MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
                result = reader.decode(binaryBitmap, hintMap);
            }catch(NotFoundException e) {
                return null;
            }
            return result.getText();
        
    }

}

But the test prints "85000" for both tests (L&M) as result. So ZXing seems to be capable of reading the QRCode with M error Correction Level just fine. What else could it be?
Here is the ZXING created QR Code with ErrorCorrection Level M:

and here is the qr code from the pdf scan with no background surrounding it. Still a NotFoundException:

and once more scanned with a higher resolution. Still a NotFoundException:

tried scanning on scanqr.org:

download from the thread with RMB->save image as:

and when you follow the link and get it there:


It's strange, this image looks identical to the one produced by Dymo.

Yeah, your are right. At first I didn't recognize that. So what the fudge is going on then? I'll try to free the QR Code from Dymo from all background now. Maybe it really is disturbing background elements...

And that's also a fail. I've freed the image from background now and still get a Not Found Exception. I've added the freed qr code to the answer above.

tried with a scan with higher resolution as well. Still NotFoundException...(image in the answer above)

Your image (even the low resolution one) scans ok at https://scanqr.org/#scan which is built using zxing. So it's not the zxing library's fault. I haven't programmed with the library myself so can't help with your code.

huh, interesting. I've tried scanqr.org right now with the scanned jpg and scanqr.org behaves exactly the same. The QR Code generated by ZXing works, the one printed and scanned does not. I've attached a screenshot to the answer above.

How did you do that? I clicked on the low-res image (https://i.sstatic.net/65kobgUB.png) and downloaded it, and then uploaded it to scanqr.org, and it worked.

Also, I viewed your screenshot of the scanqr.org page which said "No QR code found" with my Android camera, and it immediately found the QR code.

I nearly did the same. Only difference: I clicked the same image here in the thread with RMB and said "save image to" which resulted in the same image, but it seems as the image is straight B&W when you follow the link to the image whereas the rightclick shenanigans resulted in a grayscale image... Interesting to know. But maybe it really is an issue with the grayscale data confusing zxing... I've added the my 2 downloads to the answer above for shit's and giggles :D Now that I look at it, I just used the higher resolution one I think...

found this site: https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx, which can decode all images. The domain suggests which lib it is using. So the issue is probably in the way I shove the image into zxing then I guess.

I found a solution.
